# Passenger + Nodejs On CPanel server

Tags: node.js, apache, passenger, cpanel

I try to configure my cpanel server run nodejs with apache passenger module. After active module passenger in cpanel i try to run a simple nodejs example from nodejs site, but not work. I can see only the passenger friendly error page. In log of apache I can see "cannot run node" but in server node is installed correclty. 
my htaccess is:

PassengerBaseURI /
PassengerAppRoot /home/UserFolder/app

PassengerAppType  node
PassengerStartupFile app.js

thanks for any help